# Javascript read a php file, not run it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm making a dynamic csv to array formatter, and part of it displays the formatted array, and the other part is suppose to display the code for it. I can't get it to display the code without it just showing the array again, what do I do?

-Javascript

```
$.post('csv.php', {names : names, fp : fp}, function(data){
         $('#arrayDisp > center > textarea').html(data);
        $.ajax({
              url: "csv.php",
              context: document.body,
              success: function(){
                $('#codeDisp > center > textarea').html(data);
              }
        });
    });
```

-Php

```
$file = file(_FILE_PATH, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$data = array();

$line_number = 0;
foreach($file as $f) {
    $line = explode(',', $f);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($line as $l) {
        $data[$line_number][$names[$i]] = $l;
        $i++;
    }
    $line_number++;
}

json_encode($data);
print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: check the console.log(data)... ?

Comment: It runs the code, why would logging it to the console do anything different?

Comment: sounds a bit dodgy but: `echo file_get_contents(__FILE__);`

Comment: I think I'm picking up on what your saying Emissary and I'll try it really quick

Comment: Yea thanks emissary, your answer worked for me. I posted an answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Emissary's helpful hint I found the answer to my problem -

I added a request variable to my post requests and renamed them when each was over -

```
var request = 'array';
$.post('csv.php', {names : names, fp : fp, request : request}, function(data){
     $('#arrayDisp > center > textarea').html(data);
    request = 'code';
    $.post('csv.php', {names : names, fp : fp, request : request}, function(data){
        $('#codeDisp > center > textarea').html(data);
    });
});
```

Then in my php code I did this -

```
if ($_POST['request'] === "array") {
    json_encode($data);
    print_r($data);
}
else if ($_POST['request'] === "code") {
    echo file_get_contents('csv.php');
}
```

Comment: glad you got what you needed but just to point out your `json_encode` is redundant because you are not outputting it.  The `print_r` is printing PHP's output.  If you were after neatly formatted *json* you might look to echoing `json_encode` with it's "pretty print" bitmask option (php 5.4+) - [demo](http://ideone.com/acDfis)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key." has the value". $value;
}
```

This might work for you

Comment: I'm wanting to display the raw code of the php file, not run it.. besides my php file already works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify the script to accept a GET param. so it reads like this

```
if($_GET['showSource'])
  highlight_file ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
else
  //do stuff
```

So your JS call would actually be two calls, first you call the script *without* the ?showSource=1 so you will get the parsed csv thingy, then you do the call *with* the ?showSource=1 and get the source displayed.